# Converting from python list to char** and back makes all elements the same in Cython

Tags: cython

I have a Cython file called `test.pyx` with the following code:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
def test():
    x = ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
    cdef char** y = <char**> malloc(len(x) * sizeof(char*))
    for i in range(len(x)):
        item_uni = x[i].encode("UTF-8")
        y[i] = item_uni
    z = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        item = y[i]
        z.append(item)
    print(z)
```

The function should seemingly print `["a1", "a2", "a3"]`. However, it is giving me three instances of `"a3"`instead:

```
>>> test()
[b'a3', b'a3', b'a3']
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because temporary objects are involved. `item_uni` probably has always the same memory address for its contents, `y[i] = item_uni` will then point to the same address for all items, and since the last string is "a3", there will be three times "a3".

`strdup` should fix it (`free` is needed for those then)

```
from libc.string cimport strdup
...    
        y[i] = strdup(item_uni)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Can you explain a bit more in detail what free should be applied to?

Comment: @AlexanderWhatley In this case `free(y[i])` after `z.append(item)` inside the loop, and also `free(y)` after `print(z)`.